Unable to use any<Class<*>>() in MockK's every. Have to use specific class name
I can't mock method using MockK and any(). I always get MockKException: no answer found for: RestCaller(restCaller#2).call(..... I have an interface and a serivce which implements it with two overloaded methods:
interface RestCaller {
   fun <T, E> call(
        systemId: CallingSystem,
        method: String,
        responseClass: Class<T>,
        calling: () -> Response
   ): T

    fun <T, E> call(
        systemId: CallingSystem,
        method: String,
        responseClass: Class<T>,
        calling: () -> Response,
        errorResponseClass: Class<E>,
        errorResponseConverter: (E) -> ErrorModel<*>
   ): T
}

I can mock the first one like this
every { restCaller.call(any(), any(), any<Class<*>>(), any()) }.returns(mockk<SomeResponse>())

but I can't mock the second one like this:
every { restCaller.call(any(), any(), any<Class<*>>(), any(), any<Class<*>>(), any()) }.returns(mockk<SomeResponse>())

I found out that I have to use concrete class and I am able to mock it like this:
every { restCaller.call(any(), any(), SomeResponse::class.java, any(), any<Class<*>>(), any()) }.returns(mockk<SomeResponse>()).

What's wrong with overloaded method? Why adding additional two parameters makes any() don't work properly? I can't use hardcoded class name because this code is part of mocking utility module.
Test to reproduce:
package com.stackoverflow.mockk

import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.InjectMockKs
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
internal class RestCallerTest {

    @MockK
    private lateinit var restCaller: RestCaller

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var component: Component

    @Test
    fun test() {
        // works
        // every { restCaller.call<String, String>(any(), String::class.java, any()) }.returns("some result")

        // does not work
        every { restCaller.call<String, String>(any(), any(), allAny()) }.returns("some result")

        val actual = component.someMethod()

        actual.shouldBe("some result")
    }
}

interface RestCaller {
    fun <R, E> call(method: String, resultClass: Class<R>, errorClass: Class<E>): R
}

class Component(private val restCaller: RestCaller) {
    fun someMethod(): String = restCaller.call("method name", String::class.java, String::class.java)
}


For a more minimalised version, you can remove the String param at the start of the declaration of call, and just have two Class params, and the problem is still there. See https://ideone.com/EzyG1v for minimalized source code.

For some reason MockK turns every consecutive any() matcher for Class<E> into eq(class java.lang.Object).
As a workaround you can use allAny matcher instead  for the Class<E> parameter. So for the following function:
fun <T, E> call(
    responseClass: Class<T>,
    method: String,
    errorResponseClass: Class<E>,
): T

Mock would look like this:
every { restCaller.call<Any, Any>(any(), any(), allAny()) }.returns(mockk<SomeResponse>())


Update:
Unfortunately, this method doesn't work if String parameter goes first. Currently I don't have a solution for this case.

Does not work. I have complete reproducer code. I added it at the bottom of the question. Are you able to reproduce it and fix it?

I tried to use named args and bunch of other things but to no avail. As soon as String param goes before Class<> ones it stops working. Might be a bug. @Sobik

It's got nothing to do with the String param. It happens when you have two or more Class params. See my minimalised version of OP's reproducer at https://ideone.com/EzyG1v

Created MockK issue https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/1263 @k314159 thanks for confirming a bug.
